# Erro ao mostrar Sum, do SQL server, na camada DAO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, padrão-dao

Estou tento dificuldades para mostrar o resultado do SUM na camada DAO, a consulta tras o resultado esperado, porém, no campo onde é pra mostra a soma, não mostra da um erro.

A procedure no Sql Server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RelatorioDcv] @dateInicio date, @dataFim date
as
begin
select ve.Placa, sum(m.CombustivelAbastecido), count(v.VrId)
from Vr v inner join Mv m on
v.IdMv = m.Id inner join Veiculo ve on
v.IdVeiculo = ve.Id inner join Combustivel c on
ve.IdCombustivel = c.IdCombustivel
where convert(Date,v.DataEHoraServico) between @dateInicio and @dataFim
group by ve.Placa
end
```

o Código da DAO:

```
public IList<Vr> Dcv(DateTime? dataInicio, DateTime? dataFim)
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.CommandText =
                @"
               EXECUTE RelatorioDcv @dateInicio=@dataInicio, @dataFim=@dataFim
                ";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataInicio", dataInicio);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataFim", dataFim);
            SqlDataReader dr = Conexao.Selecionar(comando);

            IList<Vr> lista = new List<Vr>();
            MvDAO mdao = new MvDAO();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    Combustivel comb = new Combustivel();
                    Vr vr = new Vr();
                    vr.Veiculo = new Veiculo();
                    vr.Mv = new Mv();
                    vr.Veiculo.Placa = Convert.ToString(dr["Placa"]);
                    vr.Mv.CombustivelAbastecido = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CombustivelAbastecido"]);

                    lista.Add(vr);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lista = null;
            }
            dr.Close();
            return lista;
        }
```

O problema é justamente nesse pedaço que  teóricamente era pra mostrar a soma

```
 vr.Mv.CombustivelAbastecido = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["CombustivelAbastecido"]);
```

Não tentei mostrar o Count().

Comment: Rafael, qual o erro que aparece, especificamente?

Answer (score 2):

Olhando assim, um possível erro no código é que na hora da criação do seu objeto Combustive(), ele não esta encontrando o campo *CombustivelAbastecido*. Tente rodar a procedure no banco e verificar se estão vindo todas colunas nomeadas corretamente, geralmente no uso de Sum() a coluna vem como "(No column name)". 
Tente adicionar um nome a coluna de soma no select, ficaria assim:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RelatorioDcv] @dateInicio date, @dataFim date
    as
    begin
    select ve.Placa, sum(m.CombustivelAbastecido) as CombustivelAbastecido, 
    count(v.VrId)
    from Vr v inner join Mv m on
    v.IdMv = m.Id inner join Veiculo ve on
    v.IdVeiculo = ve.Id inner join Combustivel c on
    ve.IdCombustivel = c.IdCombustivel
    where convert(Date,v.DataEHoraServico) between @dateInicio and @dataFim
    group by ve.Placa
    end
```

Comment: Pensei que poderia ser algo do tipo mesmo... já que o comando "sum" não cria título da coluna pesquisada automaticamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui, era isso mesmo!!!

Comment: Muito bom, Rafael!